# error code "Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Tags: r, error-handling

I am using the wine data from UCI archive.

All the data points are numeric, but a couple showed integer which I changed to numeric (although I still get the error message).

```
lmwine <- lm(quality~fixed.acidity+volatile.acidity+citric.acid+residual.sugar+chlorides+
             free.sulfur.dioxide+total.sulfur.dioxide+density+pH+sulphates+alcohol,data=wineq)

summary(lm)
```

This is the error I get:

> Error in object[[i]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I don't understand. The data is simple, so is the formula. Where am I going wrong? I read other posts on the same error, and most tell that a function was used wrong, but I don't see any problem here.

Comment: `summary` does not work with functions. What you probably want to do is `summary(lmwine)`. The error message is what you get, if you try to subset a function. Try, e.g., `mean[3]` and you should see the same error message.

Comment: thank you.. that was very stupid. I should have caught that. Thanks again though.